# How to fix the line spacing in itemize environment?

Tags: line-spacing

When I use \begin{spacing}{3} ... \end{spacing} or \setlength{\baselineskip}{36pt} I got a huge space between items.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}  
\begin{document}
    
\begin{spacing}{3}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin. Praesent imperdiet mi nec ante. Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices augue, a dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede. Vivamus nunc nunc, molestie ut, ultricies vel, semper in, velit. Ut porttitor. Praesent in sapien.


\begin{align}
    5x+2y = 2z+3 \\
    5x+2y = 2z+3 \\
    13x = y+z+2 
\end{align}

\begin{itemize}
    \item first
    \item second
\end{itemize}


\begin{align}
    5x+2y = 2z+3 \\
    5x+2y = 2z+3 \\
    13x = y+z+2 
\end{align}

\end{spacing}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Use `enumitem` package and use `itemsep=(x unit)` option with `itemize`. If that is what you want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about this?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{enumitem} % <--
\setlist{noitemsep}   % <--
\begin{document}
    
\begin{spacing}{3}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam
lobortis facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra
sollicitudin. Praesent imperdiet mi nec ante. Donec ullamcorper, felis
non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices augue, a dignissim nibh
lectus placerat pede. Vivamus nunc nunc, molestie ut, ultricies vel,
semper in, velit. Ut porttitor. Praesent in sapien.
\begin{align}
    5x+2y = 2z+3 \\
    5x+2y = 2z+3 \\
    13x = y+z+2 
\end{align}
\begin{itemize}
    \item first
    \item second
\end{itemize}
\begin{align}
    5x+2y = 2z+3 \\
    5x+2y = 2z+3 \\
    13x = y+z+2 
\end{align}
\end{spacing}
\end{document}
```

[image]